# Is there a "does not build" list for groovy and if yes where is it

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a "known not to build" list for groovy and if there is where would that list be located.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51812/is-there-a-%22does-not-build%22-list-for-groovy-and-if-yes-where-is-it/) by [bobt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3863/bobt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to be more precise, a list of what: released packages that should build but fail to, or a list of any kind of package and its compatibility with groovy?

You can find a list of packages released for groovy here:
http://www.ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html

Red means that a package failed to build, grey that it's deactivated or blacklisted e.g. because of known problems.

The other list - a compilation of all known ROS packages - is not really possible due to the distributed nature. If they are not in the release system, they can be in any kind of repository, and may or may not build under ROS groovy.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4